# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment While loop error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get an error in the console when i try to run this code but i don't know why! It says this:
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment and it point to line 31

That is, the line : if (colors.indexOf(String(guess_input))=-1){

Basically what I am trying to do is check if an inputted string is part of my predefined array that you can see in the code below. The end point is a guessing game where the user has to guess a color.

```
<!DOCTYPE >
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome To The JS Guessing Game</title>
</head>
<body onload="do_game()">
<script> 

//Initialize the variables that will be needed.
var target;
var target_index;
var guess_input;
var guesses=0;
var finished=false;
var guesses=0;
var colors = ["blue", "cyan", "gold", "green", "magenta", "orange", "red", "white", "yellow"];

function do_game(){
    var random_number = (Math.random()*colors.length);
    var random_number=Math.floor(random_number);
    target=colors[random_number];
    alert(target);
    while (!finished){
        guess_input=prompt("I am thinking of a color in the list below. Can you guess which color?"+"\n\n"+ colors.join() );
        guesses++;
        finished = check_guess();  //so finished in the function has to return true for this condition to be met.
    }
}

function check_guess(){
    if (colors.indexOf(String(guess_input))=-1){
        alert("I'm sorry, I do not recognize that color! Try again.");
        return true;
    }
    else if (guess_input > target){
        alert("Your guess is alphabetically higher than the correct answer.");
        return true;
    }
    else if (guess_input < target){
        alert("Your guess is alphabetically lower than the correct answer. ");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        myBody=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        myBody.style.background=target;
        alert("You are right! You took "+guesses+" guesses!");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is the first alert window shows up telling me the color, then the prompt, but then after that, and regardless of input, the thing just stops :(
Help would be appreciated.

Cheers,

David

Comment: You need `if (... == ...)`, not `if (... = ...)`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (colors.indexOf(String(guess_input))=-1){
```

to

```
f (colors.indexOf(String(guess_input))==-1){
```

Your script basically tries to assign the value -1 to something that is not a variable.